# How can i use sed -i command to replace the occurance of character starting from particular line in a file till another line?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a text file in which I want to replace the occurrence of "#" with blank character starting from say line 10th to 20th for example 
My file is as follows:

```
some text here
some text here
some text here
#here1
#here2
#here3
#here4
#here5
erverv
ererver
```

so here from line 4 to 8 i want to remove character #. How can I achieve that using sed -i command?

Answer (score 4):

Use an address range:

```
sed -i -e '10,20s/^#//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
sed 's/#//' -i yourfile
```

With the -i flag it *edits yourfile* in place and *removes all #*
You probalby want this to only remove # at the beginning of your file

```
sed 's/^#//' -i yourfile
```

However only doing this for certain lines and not all I would recommend `awk`. See `man awk`